# C to Binary: putchar('0' + ((x>>i) & 1));

Tags: c

I am having a difficult time understanding this. My professor wrote a piece of code to go from decimal to binary and I just can't seem to understand what is going on. Can someone please explain it to me like I'm 5.

```
main() {
    int i, x = 9;
    for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        putchar('0' + ((x >> i) & 1));
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression

```
'0' + ((x>>i) & 1)
```

adds either 0 or 1 to the character `'0'`, by masking out the `i:th` bit of `x`. C guarantees that you get the character `'1'` if you add one to the character `'0'`, so this works.

The sub-expression `((x >> i) & 1)` means "take `x`, shift its value `i` bits to the right, and then do a bitwise-`AND` with the value 1". This "masks out" the `i:th` bit, so the sub-expression becomes equal to the value of that single bit of `x`.

Answer (score 4):

This commented code will hopefully make it clear:

```
// C89/C90 main() function definition with implicit return type int,
// not valid C99/C11
main(){

    int i; // loop index variable
    int x=9; // number to print as binary

    for (i=31;i>=0;i--) {
          // assume that int is 32 bits (very common even on 64 bit compilers):
          // loop will iterate from bit number 31 to bit number 0, 32 bits total
          // printing is from left to right, so bit 31 must be printed first

          // shift bits so bit number i becomes bit number 0
          int bit_i_unmasked = x >> i; 

          // set other bits to 0 by using bitwise AND operator
          int bit_i = bit_i_unmasked & 1; 
          // now bit_i has value 0 or 1

          // convert bit_i to a character, '0' or '1', 
          // calculation below is either ('0' + 0) or ('0' + 1)
          char biniary_digit = '0' + bit_i;           

          // print the digit character
          putchar(binary_digit);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Wikipedia has pretty good explanation and examples of [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) and [bit shifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) operations, of those are not clear to you.

Note about shifts: in this case it does not matter that C will do arithmetic right shift for signed integers, because the "new" bits brought in by bit shift are never used. It would make a difference, *if* `x` was negative *and* binary number was printed with more bits than `int` actually has, such as from 63 to 0 (you can try this out).