# Could somebody explain the putchar line in this bitwise function to me?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, putchar

Does anybody know what the 1u does in this function? 
The following function takes an integer and prints out its bits.
The line I am trying to figure out is the putchar line.
I see it takes an unsigned integer as an argument and iterates a one or zero in a loop the size of the binary number, which just so happens to 8*sizeof(int)  and performs an
”and” bitwise operation on the expression (1u << i)
where i is just the iteration of loop that decides how many 
bits to shift over. Is the u in 1u just a modifier to declare the number unsigned or something? 
Im trying to understand exactly how the putchar line in this function displays each bit of x with that line.

Its an & bitwise operation 
so if the bits  in x and the bits of (1u << i ) are both 1, the loop putchars 1, otherwise 0.
But since i don’t really understand what 1u is, I don’t really know  what  shifting the bits i to left is doing to 
print out the bits of x.

Could someone put it in layman's terms for me?

```
void showbits( unsigned int x )
{
    for (int i = (sizeof(int) * 8) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        putchar(x & (1u << i) ? '1' : '0');
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C to Binary: putchar('0' + ((x>>i) & 1));](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608603/c-to-binary-putchar0-xi-1)

Answer (score 3):

The code prints the binary presentation of `x`

This line

```
for (int i = (sizeof(int) * 8) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

makes `i` have values from "number_of_bits_in_an_int" - 1 and downto 0.

So if we assume that size of int is 4 (chars), the code can be written like:

```
for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
```

So in that case the loop can be expanded like:

```
putchar(x & (1u << 31) ? '1' : '0');
putchar(x & (1u << 30) ? '1' : '0');
putchar(x & (1u << 29) ? '1' : '0');
...
putchar(x & (1u <<  1) ? '1' : '0');
putchar(x & (1u <<  0) ? '1' : '0');
```

The `(1u << ..)` part can then be calculated. `1u` is an unsigned int with value 1 which is shifted left a number of times.  It produce a walking 1 bit pattern starting from MSB. Like:

```
1000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000  (i.e. 1u << 31)
0100.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000  (i.e. 1u << 30)
0010.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000  (i.e. 1u << 29)
...
0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0010  (i.e. 1u << 1)
0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0001  (i.e. 1u << 0)
```

When this pattern is bit-wise and'ed to `x` using `&` and the result used as boolean, it will generate true when the corresponding bit in `x` is 1 (and false if it is zero).

So the code can be written as this pseudo-code:

```
putchar(is_bit_31_in_x_set ? '1' : '0');
putchar(is_bit_30_in_x_set ? '1' : '0');
putchar(is_bit_29_in_x_set ? '1' : '0');
...
putchar(is_bit_1_in_x_set ? '1' : '0');
putchar(is_bit_0_in_x_set ? '1' : '0');
```

If the sizeof int isn't 4 (as assumed above) the code will still print the binary representation - just with another number of bits. For instance with sizeof int being 2, the loop will go from 15 downto 0.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. So say x is some number. It's representation in binary would be compared essentially  to a  psuedo number in binary in the sense that this psuedo binary starts 31 bits from the LSB or (1u <<31. If the bit of the actual number X in bit 31 is 1, the '&' operator compares it to the pseudo number at bit 31, if they are both 1, then the loop putchars a 1, otherwise, it putchars a zero, then this continues putcharring left to right, as it next compares bit 30 down to the LSB, essentially copying binary x. Thanks. Great explanation! Knowing what 1u does helps big time.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what `1u << i` does.

```
1 << 0    -> 0b0001 << 0     =>   0b0001      =>   1
1 << 1    -> 0b0001 << 1     =>   0b0010      =>   2
1 << 2    -> 0b0001 << 2     =>   0b0100      =>   4
1 << 3    -> 0b0001 << 3     =>   0b1000      =>   8
.
.
```

The `x` value `and`ed is to preserve sign of the number while shifting right. It is actually, in my opinion, to present how sign-extend right shift makes progress.

Comment: Very helpful visualization. Thanks.